# getting different data from db than in GraphiQL

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, graphql

I'm new to graphQL and mongoDB and I'm trying to make it work in my project. The problem is with data from query that in GraphiQL is completely different than data from the same query inside my client side. Here's my setup of schema:

```
const graphql = require('graphql');
const _ = require('lodash');
const Item = require('../models/item');
const {
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLSchema,
  GraphQLID,
  GraphQLInt,
  GraphQLList
} = graphql;

const ItemType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Item',
  fields: () => ({
    name: {
      type: GraphQLString
    },
    id: {
      type: GraphQLID
    },
    description: {
      type: GraphQLString
    },
    price: {
      type: GraphQLInt
    },
    image: {
      type: GraphQLString
    },
    category: {
      type: GraphQLString
    }
  })
});

const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'RootQueryType',
  fields: {
    item: {
      type: ItemType,
      args: {
        id: {
          type: GraphQLID
        }
      },
      resolve(parent, args) {
        // code to get data from db / other source
        return Item.findById(args.id);
      }
    },
    items: {
      type: new GraphQLList(ItemType),
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return Item.find({})
      }
    }
  }
});
```

When im doing a query from graphiQL of all the itemes and data i'm receiving is the "right one". It looks like this:[image]

When i'm doing the same exact query from the front-end like that:
import { gql } from "apollo-boost";

```
const getItemsQuery = gql`
  {
    items {
      name
      id
      description
      price
      image
      category
    }
  }
`;

export { getItemsQuery };
```

The data looks like this:
[image]

It looks like it is repeating first item over and over and i can't see why. DB is also showing right items. My server side code can be found here: https://github.com/KamilStaszewski/shoppy/tree/adding_graphQL/server [image]

Comment: It's odd indeed. It's probably a client-side issue. Maybe it has to do with the way you use your query in your React app, can you link me the file where it happens in your github or include it in your post ? I can't find it (maybe you didn't push it)

Comment: Here query is used: https://github.com/KamilStaszewski/shoppy/blob/adding_graphQL/client/src/App/Pages/MainPage.js 
and data from it is passed and mapped in this component
https://github.com/KamilStaszewski/shoppy/blob/adding_graphQL/client/src/App/Components/ShopList/ShopList.js

Comment: This looks like a caching issue. Are you using a custom instance of ApolloCache? Can you post your client configuration?

Comment: I'm new to that so i don't think im using custom instance of apollocache. Everything is default. Theres create-react-app and mongodbatlast with default configuration if you mean that my client configuration.

Comment: Could you show where you made the query call for `items` and set the performance

Comment: Here: https://github.com/KamilStaszewski/shoppy/blob/adding_graphQL/client/src/App/Pages/MainPage.js
https://github.com/KamilStaszewski/shoppy/blob/adding_graphQL/client/src/App/Queries/queries.js

Comment: Also the `items` props as well. where you set the data inside it.

Comment: The props that im consol logging on the screen is from here: https://github.com/KamilStaszewski/shoppy/blob/adding_graphQL/client/src/App/Pages/MainPage.js

Here query is called first, then data is passed to shoplist component where it is mapped.

Comment: Just a wild guess, can you empty your browser's cache to see if the error persists; maybe the browser cached an older version of your app idk

Comment: I just did after your comment and data still looks the same. : /

Comment: @DanielRearden any new ideas? i cant really move since last week with this : /

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/basics/caching.html#normalization):

> The InMemoryCache normalizes your data before saving it to the store by splitting the result into individual objects, creating a unique identifier for each object, and storing those objects in a flattened data structure. By default, InMemoryCache will attempt to use the commonly found primary keys of id and _id for the unique identifier if they exist along with __typename on an object.

In other words, Apollo will use both `__typename` and `id` to create a cache key for each `Item` you fetch. This key is used to fetch the appropriate item from the cache. The problem is that your items are returning `null` for their `id`. This results in each item being written with the same key. As a result, when your query result is returned from the cache, it looks up the same key for each item in your `items` array.

To fix this issue, you need to ensure that your API returns a value for `id`. I haven't worked with mongoose that much, but I think since mongoose adds an `id` field for you automatically based on the `_id`, it should be sufficient to just remove the `id` from your mongoose model (not your GraphQL type). Alternatively, you could try adding a resolve function to your `id` field in the GraphQL type:

```
resolve: (item) => item._id.toString()
```

Comment: Thank you. Will check that out.

Comment: You were right. After i deleted id property from my mongoose model, props was passed from graphQL correctly. Thank you very much.